# Do/does in given scenarios

Tags: verbs, auxiliary-verbs

1. When **does** your University's admission procedures start?

   or

   When **do** your University's admission procedures start?
2. When **do** his cars arrive?

   or

   When **does** his cars arrive?
3. When **does** his parents come back?

   or

   When **do** his parents come back?

In all three cases should we be using **do**, since in the first scenario, we're talking admission procedure**s**, and in the second one and third one, we're talking car**s** and parent**s**?

And, If I was to look up on the internet what I'm struggling with here, using do and does right, what should I put in the search bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in all three scenarios the proper form of the verb is **do**, not *does.*

As far as what you'd search for on the internet, I'm not positive what you're asking. But the basic issue here is subject-verb agreement. The verb form must agree with the subject in number (i.e., it must agree as far as singular/plural). In all of these cases, as you've correctly identified, the number is plural.